# StackOverflowError in Instance Initialiser

Tags: java, theory

This question is more theoretical. So I have this following set of code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Instance execution");
    }
}
```

It compiles and prints "Instance Execution".
But when I try to execute some other method this way:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Instance execution");
    }

    private void anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method execution");
    }

    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

It's giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Test.<init>(Test.java:15)
```

I'm totally convinced that this error has the easiest explanation, but my question here, is it the constructor that's throwing this error? Or only System methods can be executed this way? This whole approach of executable Instance Initialiser is very new to me, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
{
    Test test = new Test();
    test.anotherMethod();
}
```

is an instance initializer block. It runs every time you create a `Test` instance. Within it, you're...creating a new `Test` instance, which naturally triggers the block, which then creates a new `Test` instance, which triggers the block... You get the idea.

> is it the constructor that's throwing this error?

It's instance initialization, yes. And in fact, under the covers, the way instance initializer blocks are handled by the compiler is to literally copy that code into the beginning of every constructor in the class (including the default one, if you don't supply a default one), just after any call to `super` (the default one if there isn't an explicit one). So you could say it's the constructor throwing the error, even if *conceptually*, it's instance initialization as distinct from the constructor per se.

> Or only System methods can be executed this way?

Not sure what you mean by "System methods," but the issue is that the initializer block is run per-instance. If you wanted it run only once, at class initialization time, you could use a *`static`* initializer block:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Instance execution");
    }

    private void anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method execution");
    }

    static // <==================
    {
        System.out.println("Class initialization"); // ***
        Test test = new Test();
        test.anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

That outputs:

```
Class initialization
Instance execution
Method execution
Instance execution
```

*(We see "Instance execution" twice because there's one `new Test` in `main`, and another in the `static` initializer block.)*

But really, the simplest thing is to put the call to `anotherMethod` in `main`:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.anotherMethod();
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Instance execution");
    }

    private void anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method execution");
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
Instance execution
Method execution
```

Comment: Ah, that clarifies the 100 lines of errors with the same text. But would you suggest writing executable codes in Instance Initialisers in real time programming?

Comment: @RakaChowdhury: Do you literally mean "real time," or just "real"? I have no realtime programming experience in Java (and my C experience in it wouldn't be relevant, and is well out of date anyway). But if you just mean "real," my advice is: Keep instance initializers as short as possible, but no shorter. They're basically constructor code, and constructors in general should be (again) as short as possible, but no shorter. :-)

Comment: I should have just said "real" because I meant practical implementations. This answers my question. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, that you create a Test obejct in your constructor, which will create another Test object and so on. Instead use

```
this.anotherMethod();
```